logind.conf setting overriden by system settings
I have made updates to my /etc/systemmd/logind.conf file, but most of these changes seem to be ignored in favour of the settings set in Gnome Settings. How do I get Ubuntu 24.04 to use the logind settings?

Can you give a specific example? How did you determine that your setting was getting overridden by Gnome Settings - rather than by a drop in file in /etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/ or /usr/lib/systemd/logind.conf.d/ for example?

Sure thing. I have set HandlePowerKey=suspend-then-hibernate, but with the Gnome Setting for the Power Button Behavior set to None nothing happens when I press it. IdleAction=suspend-then-hibernate on the other hand works as intended when I turn off the Automatic Suspend option in Gnome Settings.
